# PHP Regex - Detect 3 <br> or newline characters

Tags: php, regex

I have data pages in Wordpess where in the data, I want to detect 3 < br > or 3 enter characters.
To detect 3 or more New Line chars,
i have : `/(^[\rn]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]{3,}+/`

I need to add and option to detect 3 new line chars or 3 < br />.
How can this be accomplished?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should do it:

```
/(?:(?=[\r\n])\r?\n?|<br[^>]+>){3,}/
```

Explanation:

- Group:

  - Either:

    - Make sure there is one of `\r` or `\n` ahead
    - Match optional `\r`, then optional `\n`
    - (This formation allows you to match all three newline formats: `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n`)
  - Or:

    - A `<br>` tag, which may contain other stuff, such as `<br />`, `<br style="clear:both">`, etc.
- Match the group three or more times.

Comment: Oh hi.. one doubt... it is detecting from 2 \r\n.. and my other code data is somewhere crashing now..

Comment: Finally I converted the br tags to newline using :<br>
`$content = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $content);`
And then the normal code to detect newlines